# How do you call something in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Okay so I have been learning to program for the vast majority of the day and I'm stumped. I looked around a bit to see how to call things and I get that you could do something like the following:

```
def add(a, b):
    return (a + b)
```

Then you would call it by planting this:

```
Answer = (1, 4)
```

The output of that would be: 5

But in my case of what I'm trying to do its not quite working out. Here is my code bellow:

```
import time

def chap4():
    print "You feel around the room.\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "You find a small chest...\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "You open the chest...\n"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "pickaxe", "shovel", "lighter", "9mm(0)", "knife" 
    while (True):
        chest = raw_input("What will you take?: ")
        if chest == "pickaxe":
            print "You take the pickaxe"
            weapon = "pickaxe"
            break
        elif chest == "shovel":
            print "You take the shovel"
              weapon = shovel
            break
        elif chest == "lighter":
            print "You take the lighter"
            weapon = "lighter"
            break
        elif chest == "9mm":
            print "You take the empty 9mm pistol"
            weapon = "9mm"
            break
        elif chest == "knife":
            print "You take the knife"
            weapon = "knife"
            break
       elif chest == "axe":
            print "You take the axe"
            weapon = "axe"
            break 
       else:
            print "Invalid choice. Try again..."
       return (chest)

class Zombie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 100

def attack(target):
    target.hp -= DAMAGE
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target.hp
    if target.hp <= 0:
    print "Zombie dies"

def attack1(target1):
    target1.hp -= DAMAGE1
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target1.hp
    if target1.hp <= 0:
    print "Zombie dies"

def attack2(target2):
    target2.hp -= DAMAGE2
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target2.hp
    if target2.hp <= 0:
    print "Zombie dies"

def attack3(target3):
    target3.hp -= DAMAGE3
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target3.hp
    if target3.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack4(target4):
    target4.hp -= DAMAGE4
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target4.hp
    if target4.hp <= 0:
    print "Zombie dies"

def attack5(target5):
    target5.hp -= DAMAGE5
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target5.hp
    if target5.hp <= 0:
    print "Zombie dies"

DAMAGE = 20
DAMAGE1 = 50
DAMAGE2 = 10
DAMAGE3 = 30
DAMAGE4 = 30
DAMAGE = 25
zombie1 = Zombie()
weapon = chap4()

print "You see a zombie in the distance"
while zombie1.hp > 0:
    user_input = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    if weapon == "knife":
        if user_input == 'stab':
            attack(zombie1)
    if weapon == "9mm":
        if user_input == 'shoot':
            attack1(zombie1)
    if weapon == "shovel":
        if user_input == "smack":
            attack2(zombie2)
    if weapon == "axe":
        if user_input == "chop":
            attack3(zombie3)
    if weapon == "pickaxe":
        if user_input == "mine":
            attack4(zombie4)
    if weapon == "lighter":
        if user_input == "burn":
            attack5(zombie5)
```

When I run the code above it goes through chap4 with no problems. However, once it gets to the zombie part it plays out but when I input my method to kill it, all it does is ask me "what will you do" a infinite number of times. It never kills the zombie. I've also tried placing the `weapon = chap4()` in many other places. This seemed the closest to success. Please help if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code appears to work *fine,* once you fix the indentation errors:

```
import time

def chap4():
    print "You feel around the room.\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "You find a small chest...\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "You open the chest...\n"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "pickaxe", "shovel", "lighter", "9mm(0)", "knife"
    while (True):
        chest = raw_input("What will you take?: ")
        if chest == "pickaxe":
            print "You take the pickaxe"
            weapon = "pickaxe"
            break
        elif chest == "shovel":
            print "You take the shovel"
            weapon = shovel
            break
        elif chest == "lighter":
            print "You take the lighter"
            weapon = "lighter"
            break
        elif chest == "9mm":
            print "You take the empty 9mm pistol"
            weapon = "9mm"
            break
        elif chest == "knife":
            print "You take the knife"
            weapon = "knife"
            break
        elif chest == "axe":
            print "You take the axe"
            weapon = "axe"
            break
        else:
            print "Invalid choice. Try again..."
    return (chest)

class Zombie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = 100

def attack(target):
    target.hp -= DAMAGE
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target.hp
    if target.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack1(target1):
    target1.hp -= DAMAGE1
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target1.hp
    if target1.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack2(target2):
    target2.hp -= DAMAGE2
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target2.hp
    if target2.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack3(target3):
    target3.hp -= DAMAGE3
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target3.hp
    if target3.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack4(target4):
    target4.hp -= DAMAGE4
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target4.hp
    if target4.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

def attack5(target5):
    target5.hp -= DAMAGE5
    print "Zombie health %s/100"%target5.hp
    if target5.hp <= 0:
        print "Zombie dies"

DAMAGE = 20
DAMAGE1 = 50
DAMAGE2 = 10
DAMAGE3 = 30
DAMAGE4 = 30
DAMAGE = 25
zombie1 = Zombie()
weapon = chap4()

print "You see a zombie in the distance"
while zombie1.hp > 0:
    user_input = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    if weapon == "knife":
        if user_input == 'stab':
            attack(zombie1)
    if weapon == "9mm":
        if user_input == 'shoot':
            attack1(zombie1)
    if weapon == "shovel":
        if user_input == "smack":
            attack2(zombie2)
    if weapon == "axe":
        if user_input == "chop":
            attack3(zombie3)
    if weapon == "pickaxe":
        if user_input == "mine":
            attack4(zombie4)
    if weapon == "lighter":
        if user_input == "burn":
            attack5(zombie5)
```

The only thing I can suggest is that you ensure you enter the correct matching items for each weapon, including case and avoiding leading or trailing white space.

You could see if there was a problem there by changing the last section to:

```
while zombie1.hp > 0:
    user_input = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    acted = False
    if weapon == "knife" and user_input == 'stab':
        attack(zombie1)
        acted = True
    if weapon == "9mm" and user_input == 'shoot':
        attack1(zombie1)
        acted = True
    if weapon == "shovel" and user_input == "smack":
        attack2(zombie2)
        acted = True
    if weapon == "axe" and user_input == "chop":
        attack3(zombie3)
        acted = True
    if weapon == "pickaxe" and user_input == "mine":
        attack4(zombie4)
        acted = True
    if weapon == "lighter" and user_input == "burn":
        attack5(zombie5)
        acted = True
    if not acted:
        print "What, are you NUTS? That won't do anything."
```